# NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate: timeout but Safari fine

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I'm using `NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:` along the lines described in [this post](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/). The problem I'm having is that when I throttle down my internet bandwidth to 2 Mb/s using Apple's [link conditioner](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/), I'm consistently getting the following error in 10 seconds or more, sometimes it even times out at 60 seconds...

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

However, opening in the same URL (a link to a file download of around 2MB) in Safari, results in the download starting almost immediately. Likewise if I use `curl`, the download starts straight away.

Why is `NSURLConnection` taking so long to connect to the web server? Is it possible my application has its network access throttled in some way? Sandboxing?

I'm on OS X 10.12 with a deployment target of 10.8. Xcode 8.2.1

**UPDATE**: I did as suggested in some of the comments and tried to reduce the problem down to a minimal reproducible example. It seems that it isn't so much `NSURLConnection` that is taking a long time to respond but that the delegate method is taking a long time to get called. I have the same problem using `NSURLSession` but only when using a delegate, not when using a block-based completion handler. I've therefore followed this up in a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927317/why-is-nsurlsessiondelegate-significantly-slower-than-nsurlsessioncompletionh)

Comment: Is there a reason why you're still using `NSURLConnection` instead of `NSURLSession`?

Comment: Is your URL http or https? In case it's http, did you added the NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary with the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads item with true value in the app plist? (That should allow any http URL; in case you just have to support one, there is another method)

Comment: @DaveWeston I'm using NSURLConnection for compatibility with older OS X targets. My deployment target is currently 10.8, but we may switch to 10.9, which also doesn't support NSURLSession

Comment: @vitormm It's https

Comment: In your shoes, I would try to isolate the problem. Try a small test app, with and without sandboxing, try `NSURLSession`. Do you have any `NSURLProtocol` code that could be interfering somehow?

Comment: DNS lookup, perhaps?